# What is the reason behind seasoning "from a distance"?

Tags: seasoning

I've seen some top chefs like Gordon Ramsay seasoning their food in the "air" or "from a distance".

Please take a look on the following example, where Chef Ramsay is seasoning a scallop:

https://youtu.be/SyBF8S_Ocf0?t=1m12s

**Why is this technique used?** Chef Ramsay specifically gives directions to season like this, so I imagine there must be a reason.

Other similar example is [this now famous Turkish chef](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2017/01/09/salt-bae-internet-falls-love-turkish-chefs-food-porn-videos/) who has become an internet sensation and meme.

Comment: Assuming it's "finishing-the-dish-before-serving seasoning", I think it is to improve the equal seasoning of every part of the dish. Seasoning from close by would most likely result in a heavily seasoned area, and most of it unseasoned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the Scallop-and-peas video, it just looks like the chef is trying to sprinkle seasoning evenly onto a relatively small area of food. If you rain seasoning down from a distance it is less likely to land unevenly than if you shake some on at close range. Imagine spray-painting a wall: for even coverage, you gotta stand back.

In the case of the Turkish meat-chef, it is because it looks cool. Notice his theatrical posture.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The turkish chef is 100% for show, but my beliefs got questioned when I saw chef Ramsay doing it -and directing others- to do it.